# how to fire druid query in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, druid

I want to fire druid query using jmeter. For example:

```
curl -L -H'Content-Type: application/json' -XPOST --data-binary @querypath/filename.json hostname @x.x.x.x:8082/druid/v2/?pretty
```

Here `filename.json` is my any druid query.

How to integrate above druid curl command query with the jmeter?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just record it using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

1. Prepare JMeter for recording. The easiest way is via [JMeter Templates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature) feature

   - From JMeter Main Menu choose `File -> Templates -> Recording` and click "Create"
   - Expand HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder and click "Start"
2. Copy `filename.json` to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation
3. Execute your [`curl` query through JMeter proxy](https://ec.haxx.se/usingcurl-proxies.html) like:

   ```
   curl -x http://localhost:8888 -L -H'Content-Type: application/json' -XPOST --data-binary @querypath/filename.json hostname @x.x.x.x:8082/druid/v2/?pretty
   ```
4. That's it, JMeter will store the relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) under the [Recording Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Recording_Controller). You will be able to replay it and see the output in the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener.